# Are there any free voice changing programs for Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, voip, voice

I would like to be able to change my voice in real-time while using any chatting software.  This would include Skype and any IP-phone software.

I found Clownfish for Skype, but was looking for something that will work across the board.

I also found [AV Voice Changer](http://www.audio4fun.com/) but its not free, nor is Voice Cloak Plus (from blazeaudio).

Comment: You want to capture the input from the microphone before the application gets it, modify the voice there, and then pass the changed voice on to any given application?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I've seen free tools to _record_ and modify, but not in real-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [MorphVOX Jr](http://www.screamingbee.com/product/MorphVOXJunior.aspx) or [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) with VST plugins can be utilized for real-time effects.

Comment: MorphVOX Jr worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear as though there are free tools to do this. Some higher-end soundcards may do this, allowing real-time effects to the placed on any inputs. I believe the Creative X-Fi drivers have this ability.